# How to debug/see log of what is causing failure?

Tags: server, 18.04

I have a fairly simple Ubuntu Server 18.04 (up to date) install. It's a fresh install from 2 weeks ago. I only have VirtualBox and phpVirtualbox (with apache) installed. Virtualbox is running only one VM (hass.io). So simple setup.

Every 2 days (gross estimate), the network hangs. The router still sees the server as active but I cannot ssh, access phpvirtualbox and connect to the VM (the VM is no more active from the router perspective though).

If I physically go to the server and open the screen, the server is not frozen but I can't login. Hitting "Enter" or Ctrl-C doesn't bring the login, it is just a black screen with a cursor and some cloud-init log. It's not frozen, the cursor changes line each time I hit enter.

How can I debug this? Where can I see a log of what is causing the network/computer to hang?

Thanks!

Maxime

Comment: `/var/log/messages` can be the first file to verify

Comment: `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show the end (`-e`) of the previous boot (`-b -1`). `-b -2` will show the one before that. `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show network logs. Read `man journalctl`

Comment: Thank you! I had some errors regarding UWF killing connections but when I do ufw status it's inactive. I saw some stuff about cloud-init so I uninstalled it. I'll monitor if my server stops again.